# How to trigger paste event before any keypress/keyup/keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am having two textarea having id's textareaOne and textareaTwo.

I am inserting mobile number in the textareaOne using paste event and parsing and displaying in textareaTwo.

Also , I am enabling user to enter phone number manually in textareaOne 
and once the entered input length is 10, I am displaying in textareaTwo.

**paste**:

```
$('#textareaOne').on('paste', function (event) {
    var pastedInputData = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    // validation
    $("#textareaTwo").val(pastedInputData );
    }
```

**keyup/keydown/keypress**:

```
    $("#textareaOne").keyup(function(){
       var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
       //validation
      $("#textareaTwo").append(enteredInput);
    });
```

Whenever I try to paste records in textareaOne using different browser

> CHROME: Working as excepted.
>
> FIREFOX: Triggering keyup event instead of paste event.

Can any one Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Chrome 50 + Firefox 46.. They both work as expected.. https://jsfiddle.net/j1qc18s8/1/

Comment: @choz  I am using firefox 45.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=paste

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to do different things?
Could you try something like this?

```
// Copy text
function copyText() {
  $("#textareaTwo").val($('#textareaOne').val());
}

$('#textareaOne').on('paste', copyText);
$("#textareaOne").keyup(copyText);
```

Comment: I have created a separate function to read input data and performs validation and to display in textareaTwo. What'z my issue is when I paste records  in textareaOne , Itz calling keydown event and nothing is pasted in the textareaOne.